# Как заблокировать всплывающие окна alert?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webbrowser

Использую в проекте компонент WebBrowser и возникла проблема с блокировкой  окон, которые инициируются JS.

[Пример всплывающего окна, необходимо нажать на кнопку Click Me](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_error_handling.htm)

Пытаюсь заблокировать всплывающие окна следующим образом:

```
using mshtml;
..................
HtmlElement head = webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptElement = webbrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptElement.DomElement;
element.text = @"alert = function(){};";
head.AppendChild(scriptElement);
```

Выполнял код после полной загрузки страницы. Код успешно выполняется, но всплывающие окна всё равно всплывают.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно заблокировать эти всплывающие окна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

> It's the WebBrowserSite, not the WebBrowser that needs to implement

IDocHostShowUI:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WebBrowserMessageBox
{
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct POINT
  {
    public int x;
    public int y;
  }

  [ComImport, Guid("C4D244B0-D43E-11CF-893B-00AA00BDCE1A"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
  public interface IDocHostShowUI
  {
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int ShowMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpstrText,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpstrCaption,
      int dwType,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpstrHelpFile,
      int dwHelpContext,
      out int lpResult);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int ShowHelp(
      IntPtr hwnd,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszHelpFile,
      int uCommand,
      int dwData,
      POINT ptMouse,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pDispatchObjectHit);
  }

  public class ShowMessageEventArgs : EventArgs
  {
    public ShowMessageEventArgs(string text, string caption, int type, string helpFile, int helpContext)
    {
    }

    public bool Handled { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; private set; }
    public int HelpContext { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public string Caption { get; private set; }
    public string HelpFile { get; private set; }
  }

  public class MyWebBrowser : global::System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
  {
    protected class MyWebBrowserSite : global::System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.WebBrowserSite, IDocHostShowUI
    {
      private readonly MyWebBrowser host;

      public MyWebBrowserSite(MyWebBrowser host)
        : base(host)
      {
        this.host = host;
      }

      public int ShowMessage(IntPtr hwnd, string lpstrText, string lpstrCaption, int dwType, string lpstrHelpFile, int dwHelpContext, out int lpResult)
      {
        var e = new ShowMessageEventArgs(lpstrText, lpstrCaption, dwType, lpstrHelpFile, dwHelpContext);
        this.host.OnShowMessage(e);

        if (e.Handled)
        {
          lpResult = e.Result;
          return 0;
        }
        else
        {
          lpResult = 0;
          return 1;
        }
      }

      public int ShowHelp(IntPtr hwnd, string pszHelpFile, int uCommand, int dwData, POINT ptMouse, object pDispatchObjectHit)
      {
        return 1;
      }
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserSiteBase CreateWebBrowserSiteBase()
    {
      return new MyWebBrowserSite(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnShowMessage(ShowMessageEventArgs e)
    {
      var handler = this.Events["ShowMessage"] as EventHandler<ShowMessageEventArgs>;

      if (handler != null)
      {
        handler(this, e);
      }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ShowMessageEventArgs> ShowMessage
    {
      add { this.Events.AddHandler("ShowMessage", value); }
      remove { this.Events.RemoveHandler("ShowMessage", value); }
    }
  }

  public static class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
      var webBrowser = new MyWebBrowser
      {
        Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill,
        DocumentText = @"<html><head><body><script language='JScript'>alert(""test"")</script></body></head></html>"
      };
      webBrowser.ShowMessage += (sender, e) =>
      {
        e.Result = 0;
        e.Handled = true;
      };

      var form = new global::System.Windows.Forms.Form
      {
        Controls = { webBrowser }
      };

      global::System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form);
    }
  }
}
```

[Ссылка на первоисточник](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8b0712ca-0b92-4e3d-a243-27af57a57213/idochostshowui-problem-c-webbrowser?forum=ieextensiondevelopment)