# Некорректно работает WebBrowser с JS

Tags: javascript, c#, yandex-maps-api, webbrowser

Приветствую!

При работе с WebBrowser возникли проблемы, при выполнении JS выдает ошибку, однако при открытии в Google Chrome никаких ошибок нет.

Код HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="circle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width:300px; height:300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Код JS:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [60.000000, 30.000000],
    zoom: 10
});
var myCircle = new ymaps.Circle([
    [60.000000, 30.000000],
    01000
], {
    balloonContent: "Радиус круга - 10 м",
}, {
    draggable: false,
    fillColor: "#DB709350",
    strokeColor: "#990066",
    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
    strokeWidth: 2
});
myMap.geoObjects.add(myCircle);
}
```

Оба кода взяты из [*песочницы яндекса*](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.0/circle), являются полностью рабочими. Помогите заставить WebBrowser работать как надо.
Укажите мне путь истинный.

пс: засунул в свой проект Awesomium, он ошибок не выдает но и не отображает ничего, но это думаю из за неправильной настройки, впервые им пользуюсь.

**Новости по ошибке:**

**1** Для того что бы не было ошибок в выполнении JS, необходимо в html  файл добавить код указывающий на контент, так как Default - ie6.
Код, который необходимо добавить:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

Однако это не решило всех проблем, теперь WebBrowser ведет себя как Awesomiun, все работает не выдает ошибок, но карту не отображает по каким то причинам.

**2** Наконец таки карта отобразилась но не работают элементы(кнопки приблизить отдалить и тд), а так же не перетаскивается карта зажатием лкм, ее можно только масштабировать колесиком.

Comment: А `WebBrowser` какую ошибку показывает? Что говорит? подробненько

Comment: Ошибка 1: локальный файл JS, исходник коего выше.
"На этой странице произошла ошибка сценария"
Предполагается наличие идентификатора, строки или числа и указывает если посмотреть на код в вопросе на это место "], {".
Вы хотите продолжить выполнение сценария? да/нет

Ошибка 2: https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU
"На этой странице произошла ошибка сценария"
Script error.
Вы хотите продолжить выполнение сценария? да/нет

Прошу прощения за столь убогое форматирование текста, в комментариях не работает интер? Вроде в редакторе все нормально а при сохранении ужас..

Comment: На этой странице произошла ошибка сценария решается путем установки свойства  WebBrowser1.Silent=true. По блокировке алертов задавал вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513062/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-webbrowser-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-alert%d0%b0

Comment: Мне требуется исключить ошибки, а не заблокировать окна с ошибками... Блокировка ошибок не ведет к решению проблемы..
Все ошибки со скриптами и отображением решены, осталось лишь понять почему в webBrowser не работает перетаскивание карты, а в webControl работает.

Comment: ааа, вот оно что)) еще, как вариант заставить webbrowser использовать последнюю версию IE ПК возможно это поможет Вам решить оставшуюся проблему. попробуйте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-ie-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: Если бы вы были повнимательнее, то увидели бы что это я уже сделал, и написал об этом в сам вопрос. Проблему решил радикально, окончательно уйдя от webBrowser заменив его Awesomium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с отображением содержимого в webBrowser была решена этим кодом

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

Остальные проблемы были решены переходом на Awesomium.